# How to output in html if a record from php mysql has 'ñ'?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a list of records but let's take this for example

John
Kenneth
Lorenz
Minnie
Niño

When i process a Select query to give me all names, it does but the last record shows Ni�o instead of Niño. How should i do it?

Answer (score 0):

you must set the mysql connection charset when building a mysql connection :

```
$conn = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password);
mysql_set_charset("UTF8", $conn);
```

Comment: ooooh that worked.. Thank you @PiML  <3 <3

Comment: @PatrickJohnCalumno Your welcome, also you have to set the utf8 charset for your table/db in order to safely store the data.